# Rails Concurrency Issue With MS SQL While Storing Incremental Values in DB

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

I am running an application that uses rails 3.2.3 and sits on top of an instance of MS SQL Sever using tinyTDS to connect. The application is multithreaded using unicorn to have 4 processes. The issue is that the application uses a field in the database in order to store a number that needs to be incremented in order to assign each request a unique account number. When I run the application locally there is no issue since it is not multithreaded.

When I am running in our staging environment using unicorn and when I hit the application with multiple concurrent request 1 out of every 10 or so comes back with a duplicate card number. I have tried the following.

**Legacy Code**

```
row = CardValue.find_by_name("next_card_number") \ or raise "Missing next_card_number row in card_values table"
next_card_number = row.value
row.value = (next_card_number.to_i + 1).to_s
row.save!
return next_card_number
```

**Legacy Code + Transaction**

```
CardValue.transaction do
  row = CardValue.find_by_name("next_card_number") \ or raise "Missing next_card_number row in card_values table"
  next_card_number = row.value
  row.value = (next_card_number.to_i + 1).to_s
  row.save!
  return next_card_number
end
```

*Result:* No effect

**Legacy Code + with_lock**

```
CardValue.with_lock do
  row = CardValue.find_by_name("next_card_number") \ or raise "Missing next_card_number row in card_values table"
  next_card_number = row.value
  row.value = (next_card_number.to_i + 1).to_s
  row.save!
  return next_card_number
end
```

*Result:* Error that with_lock is undefined

**Legacy Code + with_lock**

```
CardValue.transaction do
  lock!
  row = CardValue.find_by_name("next_card_number") \ or raise "Missing next_card_number row in card_values table"
  next_card_number = row.value
  row.value = (next_card_number.to_i + 1).to_s
  row.save!
  return next_card_number
end
```

*Result:* Error that lock is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction is not what you are looking for if your issue is concurrency`. A transaction is created to ensure the proper order of a certain database command and the possibility to roll it back if errors occur. this is not what you are looking for.

`.with_lock` should be called on a instance. so not  `CardValue.with_lock` but `my_found_card.with_lock`.

Also. why are you creating a `unique id` from rails? Mysql/mariadb can handle that for you easy with a auto increment primary key

Comment: Having rails generate it is a business requirement from the legacy system, because they are tied to another system. Not something I can change.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rails docs, `with_lock` is applied to an instance rather than the class. This is an alternate implementation of your **Legacy Code + with_lock** example.

```
row = CardValue.find_by_name("next_card_number") or raise "Missing next_card_number row in card_values table"
row.with_lock do
  next_card_number = row.value
  row.value = (next_card_number.to_i + 1).to_s
  row.save!
  return next_card_number
end
```